# Google maps and Google charts on the same page

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

For some reason, I can't load both the Google maps v3 API and the Google charts API in the same page.

I've created [a minimal JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3Sg8m/) showing a working map.

However, if I load the charts API by uncommenting the line:

```
   google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
```

... then suddenly the map doesn't appear, with no error on the console.

I've tried this on recent Chrome.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform load before of event listener like in [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Sg8m/1/)

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    //google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
        window.map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.querySelectorAll('#map')[0], {
            zoom: 2,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        });
    });
});
```

or you can do that dynamically  with a callback like described in google docs [Dynamic Load](https://developers.google.com/loader/#Dynamic).

See also [google.load('visualization'…) bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947924/google-loadvisualization-bug).

Comment: Setting the load callback as describe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947924/google-loadvisualization-bug) fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @Anto Jurković, take care with that: it is possible with that method for the API to load before document load fires, and thus the callback is registered too late and is never called.  If you must wait for document load, then google.load should be called from within the document load handler to ensure that the callback runs.

Answer (score 1):

There is (usually) no need to wait for document load to draw stuff with the Visualization API.  Use this format instead:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
    window.map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.querySelectorAll('#map')[0], {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // do other stuff on document load
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/3Sg8m/2/